# Iterating through file line by line in AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I am trying to figure out how to iterate through a file line by line in AppleScript. Similar to a bash script like so:

```
for LINE in $(cat file)
do
   echo ${LINE}
done
```

Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't take credit for writing this, I lifted the code from a [response to a post](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?s=0b16a50f0a89ffd0e2317ba147e7604e&p=1434894&postcount=2) in the MacRumors forums.

```
tell application "Finder"
  set Names to paragraphs of (read (choose file with prompt "Pick text file containing track names"))
  repeat with nextLine in Names
    if length of nextLine is greater than 0 then
      --Do something with the next name, which is stored in "nextLine"
    end if
  end repeat
end tell
```

Original code credit to [HexMonkey](http://forums.macrumors.com/member.php?s=0b16a50f0a89ffd0e2317ba147e7604e&u=29160) on the MacRumors forum.

Comment: There's no need to tell the Finder to do these things. You should take all of that code out of the Finder tell block. Applescript can handle that code itself and the Finder is often busy with other tasks so it may even slow the code down.

Comment: Good to know. I really should learn applescript myself one of these days. :P